# Is the set of all matrices $A$ that have $Tr(BAB)=0$ ($B$ is any fixed matrix) a vector space?

Tags: matrices, trace

I'm really struggling to write the $tr(BAB)$ with the formal definition (sigma and products).
I would appreciate it if someone can help me with how I approach questions like these with traces and products of matrices.
Thanks

Comment: Is $B$ fixed? Or is it "there exists a $B$ such that..."?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: Oh yes B is fixed, the question was like: B is a fixed matrix (nxn), is the set of all matrices A (nxn) that have tr(BAB)=0  a vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that something is a vector space you need it to be closed under addition an scalar multiplication.  So assume that $\operatorname{tr}(BAB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA'B)=0$.  Let us use properties of traces (but not the definition):
$$\operatorname{tr}(B(A+A')B)=\operatorname{tr}(BAB+BA'B)=\operatorname{tr}(ABA)+\operatorname{tr}(BA'B)=0+0=0.$$

Similarly, if $c$ is a scalar, we have
$$\operatorname{tr}(B(cA)B)=\operatorname{tr}(c(BAB))=c\operatorname{tr}(BAB)=c\cdot 0 = 0.$$

The first calculation tells us that our space is closed under sums.  The second tells us that our space is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really opened my eyes on how to approach these questions, appreciate it!

Comment: @Joseph you are welcome. In general, it is helpful to establish nice properties of things and then use those whenever possible. This makes things easier to understand and generalize. It is not always possible, so do not feel like going back to definitions is a failure of any sort, just ask “does this follow from established properties” when working with problems and you might find the answer is yes.

Comment: Appreciate all the help and the tips !! :), I was wondering what would the answer be if it was tr(ABA) and not tr(BAB). I tried it myself and got that it isn't really a vector space because it's not closed under addition, do you approve?

Comment: @Joseph Yes, the existence of two As makes this nonlinear. As an exercise, you might try to find an example of two matrices A and A’ such that $tr(A^2)=tr(A’^2)=0$ but their sum does not satisfy this condition. This is the case B=I

Answer (score 0):

To complement Aaron's nice answer, one could also notice that the map

$$f \colon \mathrm{Mat}(n \times n, k) \to k, \ \ \ \ \ A \mapsto \mathrm{tr}(BAB)$$

is linear. (Here, $k$ is any field and $\mathrm{Mat}(n \times n, k)$ is the space of $n \times n$-matrices with entries in $k$). Of course, one proves this with similar arguments as in Aaron's answer.

Then your desired space is just the kernel of $f$, hence a vector subspace of $\mathrm{Mat}(n \times n, k)$.

Comment: While the same work is required to show linearity of the map, this perspective gives something my answer did not: the dimension of this space is is $n^2-1$ by the rank-nullify theorem. For most $B$, at least (e.g., if $B^2\neq 0$)

Comment: I really appreciate the help! to be honest I'm still in the beginning of my course and still don't really know what the map is, but this just shows me how much more stuff I will have in the future to use to solve or understand the problems. I will try to come back here once I learn about it. Thank you so much!!